# Laravel - Foreach loop Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eloquent

I have a database table with

`id | name | url | 
  1 | Bike | bike|
  2 | Auto | auto|`

I want to fetch the all **names** from the table to view with foreach loop. But it returns

> Trying to get property of non-object

**Controller**

```
public function category($url, request $id)
{
    $cat = Category::where('url', $url)->firstorfail();
    return view ('view', compact('category'));  
}
```

**Model**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'url'];
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach($category as $cat)
    {{ $cat->name }}
    //{{ $cat['name] }} does not return anything.
@endforeach

//{{ $cat->name }} returns only one category name
```

I saw [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789749/foreach-error-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object), I couldn't solve it.

Comment: You are getting 1 model via `firstorfail` but in the view you are iterating ... either remove the `foreach` or pass an array of `Category`

Comment: I tried replacing ``firstorfail`` with ``get()``, still no success. If I tried ``$cat->all()``. Its ``Call to a member function all() on boolean``. It is the issue?

Comment: `get` is used when specifing a `where` clause with/or sorting. If you want to display 1 item remove the `foreach` in the template. If you want multiple then pass to the view the array

Answer (score 1):

`$cat = Category::where('url', $url)->firstorfail();` this only return one collection, not array of collection. If you want to return all the values then use `get()`:

```
$category = Category::where('url', $url)->get();
return view ('view', compact('category'));
```

Comment: Tried but not worked. ``Trying to get property of non-object``

Comment: Can you show the output of `dd($category)` before return statement inside https://pastebin.com/

Comment: I mean `dd` this one `$category = Category::where('url', $url)->get();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display 1 category you should have:

**Controller**

```
public function category($url, request $id)
{
    $category = Category::where('url', $url)->firstorfail();
    return view ('view', compact('category'));  //sends 1 entity to the view
}
```

**Model**

```
class Category extends Model
 {
      protected $fillable = ['name', 'url'];
 }
```

**View**

```
  {{-- Removed the foreach becaus you have 1 entity sent from the controller --}}
  {{ $category->name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function category($url, request $id)
{
$cat = Category::where('url', $url)->firstorfail();
return view ('view')->with('category',$cat);  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks